# Android use of Service in an Activity

Tags: android, service

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Preview extends Activity {

    public Preview() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
        String pkg = Service.class.getPackage().getName();
    }
}
```

I am curious about the use of `Service.class.getPackage().getName();`. I see the package name is gotten. My question is on the use of Service.class. What is meant by that or what object is being accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this is used to initialize classes in Java (the know pattern is Class.forName("some.Clazz") ). It forces a class to be loaded and its static fields to be initialized (eg. commonly for JDBC drivers).

Now you're under andoid (then dalvik), where did you get this pattern?

Comment: It is a live wallpaper example. I see now what you meant about initializing static types. The use of .class I initially did not understand. Thank you for clarifying this the is initializing the static members of the class Service which is defined elsewhere in the example in another .java file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a roundabout to get a String containing `"android.app"`. As a side effect, it also loads the Service class (which is completely useless since it's a framework class and doesn't have any static initializers). If you're looking for the application's package name (the one declared in the manifest), you really should do `this.getPackageName()` (since `Activity` is a `Context`)

Answer (score -1):

> - A facility for the application to tell the system about something it    wants to be doing in the background (even when the user is not
>     directly interacting with the application). This corresponds to calls 
>     to Context.startService(), which ask the system to schedule work for
>     the service, to be run until the service or someone else explicitly
>     stop it.
> - A facility for an application to expose some of its functionality to    other applications. This corresponds to calls to
>     Context.bindService(), which allows a long-standing connection to be
>     made to the service in order to interact with it

Source: [Android Dev Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Source: [What is a service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService)